# GenButton alignment wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

i am struggling to find an answer to the alignment of my GenButton,
i have looked through the docs on wxpython website and cant see any option in there to address this, hopefully one of you guys can point me in the right direction, as i need to align my buttons to the center of the catpanel, here is my code so far.

```
import wx, os, os.path
from wx.lib.buttons import GenButton

class Home(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=(1024, 576),style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(107, 109, 109))

        self.catpanel()


    def catpanel(self):
        homepanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        homepanel.BackgroundColour = (86, 88, 88)
        homepanel.SetSize((1024, 40))
        GenButton(homepanel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Home", style=wx.NO_BORDER, size=(-1, 40))

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Home(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

`

i am using windows, i also understand this can be acheived by using `pos = wx.DefaultPosition` but would like a more accurate wx way of doing this, could someone inspect the code and let me know if i am doing it right as i am new to wxpython / python in general

tnx

Comment: Plus 1 for posting a seemingly easy, but not completely trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI toolkits tend to be smart about size of controls: You specified the height of our `GenButton` instance but not the width (`size=(-1, 40)`). If you adapt the button width to the parent panel width, you will get what you want (`size=(1024, 40)`).

However, this is not what you should do, because you would use sizers. With the style `wx.NO_BORDER` for the `wx.Frame` you seem to have hit another snafu, where sizers do not work as expected together with `GenButton`.

```
class Home(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(107, 109, 109))

        homepanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn = GenButton(homepanel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Home", style=wx.NO_BORDER, size=(-1, 40))
        sz.Add(btn, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0)
        # Dummy placeholder with heigth already set
        sz.Add((-1, 400), 1)

        homepanel.SetSizer(sz)
        # try to uncomment next line: without resizing
        # the window will not be layouted
        self.SetSize((1024, -1))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
```

Comment: Right i think i see what you are getting at, In order to center my genbutton i need to create a vertical boxsizer and center that, then add my genbutton to the vertical boxsizer i just created ?     this way i can add more buttons left or right of center button by specifying a new vertical boxsizer, genbutton id and position ?

Comment: To understand sizers you should consult the [wxPython demo](https://wxpython.org/download.php) examples for different kinds of sizer application. It has a special section regarding all different sizers. You should be far less concerned regarding setting control sizes and let sizers do the work. In your case you would arrange n buttons in a ``BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)`` and specifying a proportion of 1 for each button.

Comment: this has helped thankyou, i can see how my code was not really in logic, even though i still struggling to get the buttons center alligned the way i want, am i right in understanding that you mean dont worry bout the window size, just worry bout getting the buttons in place ?

Comment: What I was trying to say: The core controls of wxPython are good at it to determine their minimum size required to be useful (taking things like underlying GUI-toolkit, system font size and the similar into account without requiring you to care about that). So the only thing left for you to do is to choose a control layoutusing sizers and decide the proportion occupying in the control. Your question was special because ``GenButton`` as generic control seems not to be good at determining its minimum size and needed some nudging.